How can i turn this pinescript indicator into a ctrader indicator?
i have a multi-timeframe pinescript indicator that i wish to convert into a ctrader indicator. These are the rules for calculation :

Calculate the 9 period hull moving average using the open price as the source for the 1 hour timeframe. Name this as “HMA 9 period 1 hour”
Calculate the 9 period hull moving average using the open price as the source for the 5 minutes timeframe. Name this as “HMA 9 period 5 mins””
Calculate the momentum of the “HMA 9 period 1 hour” by subtracting the current value of “HMA 9 period 1 hour” from the value of “HMA 9 period 1 hour” of the previous candle. Name this as “momentum 1 hour”
Calculate the momentum of the “HMA 9 period 5 mins” by subtracting the current value of “HMA 9 period 5 mins” from the value of “HMA 9 period 5 mins” of the previous candle. Name this as “momentum 5 mins”
Calculate the sum of “momentum 5 mins” and “momentum 1 hour” and plot the result as a histogram which has a red color if it is <0 and a green color if it is >0. Name this as “oscillator”

This is the pinescript code for the indicator :
//@version=5
indicator(title="Momentum oscillator copy 2", shorttitle="Mom oscillator copy 2", timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
lengthInput = input.int(9, title="Length")
tf=input.timeframe(title="Timeframe 5 mins",defval="5")
hull9open  = ta.hma(open , lengthInput)
hull9open5mins=request.security(syminfo.tickerid,tf,hull9open,gaps=barmerge.gaps_on)
momhull9open = hull9open-hull9open[1]
momhull9open5mins = hull9open5mins-hull9open5mins[1]
osc = momhull9open+momhull9open5mins
plot(osc , color = osc>0? color.green : color.red , title = "osc" , style = plot.style_columns)

you will also find an attached photo of what the indicator looks like Pinescript indicator
i tried coding the same indicator in ctrader (which uses C#) but the indicator does not have the same values as in pinescript , does not change color when oscillating around the zero level , and is really far offset from the current price candlesticks as shown in the attached photo ctrader indicator(last indicator value is at 16th of December while the actual price continues until 23rd of December). So how can i make it look the same as Tradingview's pinescript ?
This is the code i wrote :
using System;
using cAlgo.API;
using cAlgo.API.Collections;
using cAlgo.API.Indicators;
using cAlgo.API.Internals;

namespace cAlgo
{
    [Indicator(AccessRights = AccessRights.None)]
    public class Momentumoscillator2 : Indicator
    {
        [Parameter(DefaultValue = 9)]
        public int Period { get; set; }
        
        [Output("Momentumoscillator", LineColor = "Green")]
        public IndicatorDataSeries Momentumoscillator { get; set; }

        private MovingAverage hull5mins;
        private MovingAverage hull60mins;

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // Use MarketSeries for the current time frame
            var bars5 = MarketData.GetBars(TimeFrame.Minute5);
            var bars60 = MarketData.GetBars(TimeFrame.Hour);

            // Initialize Moving Averages for 5-minute and 60-minute bars
            hull5mins = Indicators.MovingAverage(bars5.OpenPrices, Period, MovingAverageType.Hull);
            hull60mins = Indicators.MovingAverage(bars60.OpenPrices, Period, MovingAverageType.Hull);
        }

        public override void Calculate(int index)
        {
            // Ensure index is greater than 0 to avoid out-of-bounds errors
            if (index <= 0)
            return;
            {
                // Calculate oscillator values based on the differences between consecutive moving averages
                double oscillator5mins = hull5mins.Result[index] - hull5mins.Result[index - 1];
                double oscillator60mins = hull60mins.Result[index] - hull60mins.Result[index - 1];

                // Combine both oscillators
                double oscillatorvalue = oscillator5mins + oscillator60mins;

                // Assign calculated value to Momentumoscillator
                Momentumoscillator[index] = oscillatorvalue;
            }
        }
    }
}

